# Using SharpZipLib to update a zip - something bad if the entry name includes folder

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib

This is my code to update an existing zip, the callers pass in the ZipFile and have a finally block to close the zipfile.

```
    private static void AddFiles(ZipFile zipFile, string path, string filesEntryLocation, string pattern = @"*") {

        zipFile.BeginUpdate();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);

        foreach (string filename in files) {
            zipFile.Add(filename, (filesEntryLocation + filename.Split(new[] { '\\' }).Last()).Replace('\\','/'));
        }



        zipFile.CommitUpdate();
    }
```

As you can see I'm adding entries into the zip and setting the entryname to be in a specific part of the zip folder hierarchy.

We are doing this to inject a product into a 'framework' web package - the framework supports loosely coupled products.

The result zip is fine, I can navigate it in Windows, I can extract it...
BUT MSDeploy comes along and where ever a new entry resulted in an addition to zip folder hierarchy, I get errors from msdeploy saying it couldn't open the zip - BUT only at that specific i.e. the zip is not completely corrupt, it's only where msdeploy starts navigating done a 'new' folder.

Now, if I extract the changed zip, and then re-zip it (using 7zip), and ask msdeploy to execute against that - no problem it works.

SO - is this SharpZipLib, or am I doing something wrong in adding to the zip folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You should also add the folder entries to archive (if they do not exist before).